# What is difference between users_user_permissions and auth_permission and auth_group_permissions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Django autogenerated above tables with syncdb, but I can't understand what are those tables for.
Sorry for silly question, but I'm just started with groups and permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django's scheme for automatically generating table names is explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names). Basically, it uses the pattern *app_model*. In the case of ManyToManyFields—which are implemented by creating a new table to hold the relationship—this becomes *app_model1_model2s*.

So:

**auth_permission** is the table that represents the `auth.Permission` model.

**auth_group_permissions** is the table that represents the ManyToMany relationship between `auth.Group` and `auth.Permission`.

**users_user_permissions** is the table that represents the `ManyToManyField` between `users.User` and `auth.Permission`. (I assume this is coming from an app you're using? Django's `contrib.auth` version should be `auth_user_user_permissions`.)

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) for how these tables are actually used.